# Declaring Global Variables with a Singleton in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, variables, save, global-variables, global

I am looking for the most optimal way to store and read variables globally across all my classes. I understand I could use a 'singleton' however I wasn't sure whether this was the best method for storing my variables or how to go about doing this exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use singletons and here is how I do it:

Create a new class, for the demonstration here we will name it `MyDataModel`. In **MyDataModel.h** do the following:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyDataModel : NSObject
{
    NSString *myStringVariable;
    NSUInteger myIntVariable;
    //add any variables you need
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myStringVariable;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger myIntVariable;

+ (MyDataModel *) sharedInstance;

@end
```

Now in the **MyDataModel.m** do:

```
#import "MyDataModel.h"

@implementation MyDataModel

@synthesize myStringVariable, myIntVariable;

static MyDataModel *_sharedInstance;

+ (MyDataModel *) sharedInstance
{
    if(!_sharedInstance)
    {
        _sharedInstance = [[MyDataModel alloc] init];
    }
    return _sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

Now in any class you want to use this singleton you have to `#import` this class and here is how to use the variables:

```
[MyDataModel sharedInstance].myStringVariable = @"anyThing";
[MyDataModel sharedInstance].myIntVariable = 123;
```

I hope this clarifies things for you.

Comment: I assume these variables are like normal ones. How would I go about saving them so that when the user returns they would remain the same? I was thinking that 'NSUserdefaults' would be the best option for this.

Comment: To decide about "best option" for saving we have to know the data types an quantity. If as you are saying that they are normal ones then yes NSUserdefaults is a good choice for its simplicity of use. Another option could be a normal file on the disk, you put the things you want to save in an array and `[array writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];`. There are other options as well like SQLite3 databse but sure this is used when you have large data to store... So the type and quantity of the data decides.

Comment: In total I only have about 7 variables so I think that NSUserDefaults would suit me in this case.

Comment: Also just to clarify, the last two pieces of code are setting the values of the variables, am I right? If so how do I simply read these like it was a normal string or int lets say.

Comment: 7 variables are not much, so NSUserDefaults should be ok. Reading from these variables is the same way as writing: `anotherString = [MyDataModel sharedInstance].myStringVariable;` or `anotherInteger = [MyDataModel sharedInstance].myIntVariable;`. I hope I understood your comment correctly. Please consider to set this answer as correct if it solved your problem so other readers can know that this answer is the solution for your question.

Comment: I appear to be getting this error - 'Type of property 'MyVariable' ('unsigned int') does not match type of ivar 'MyVariable' ('unsigned int *') - Not sure what's causing it.

Comment: This error is not related to having a Singleton, it seems there is type mismatch between your variables. Check the line on which the error appears and check the variable types. Also be sure that the type of the variable declared in the class matches the type in the `@property` line.

Comment: I found the issue, It's to do with the declaration of the variables. The '*' (Star) wasn't needed.

Comment: Yes sorry, it is a copy/paste error in my code, if you notice I had the * in the class definition but not in the `@property`. I will fix it. After all only objects take * in declaration. `NSUInteger` is not an object, it is a wrap for `unsigned int`, so it doesn't take a *.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSUserDefaults, Variables in the AppDelegate (not advised), or a singleton.
I always create a singleton in my apps to store all sorts of variables and methods.